# to increase font size in c graphics

Tags: c, linux, graphics, ubuntu-10.04

How to increase the font size in the c graphics/ I know one of the functions and that is settextstyle(), but the graphics package installed in my system does not have this function. So how can I do this ?
PS : I'm using libgraph-1.0.2 package. 
Please Help !

Comment: Qt? GTK? wxWidgets? OpenGL? ...